# Why do some functions of Intel IPP do not support unsigned bytes?

Tags: intel-ipp

I noticed that some (maybe most, I didn't check all of them) functions of the Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) do not support signed bytes (8s), such as
[SortAscend and SortDescend](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-1-signal-and-data-processing/essential-functions/conversion-functions/sortascend-sortdescend.html) and [Copy](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-1-signal-and-data-processing/vector-initialization-functions/vector-initialization-functions-1/copy.html), for example.

I cannot think of a reason why this would be the case, does somebody else know?

Comment: functions of the Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) do not support signed bytes (8s)
>> Would you mean in terms of 1 byte only?
You could use <16 bit depth> signed integers as well which serves the purpose.

Intel IPP is built using the compiler option /Zp16, which aligns the structure fields on the field size or 16 bytes if the size is greater than 16. You can also use the ippsMalloc function to align the allocated memory pointer on 64 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

functions of the Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) do not support signed bytes (8s)

> > You could use <16 bit depth> signed integers which serves the purpose. Intel IPP is built using the compiler option /Zp16, which aligns the structure fields on the field size or 16 bytes if the size is greater than 16. You can also use the ippsMalloc function to align the allocated memory pointer on 64 bytes.